# Implementing __getitem__

Tags: python

Is there a way to implement `__getitem__` in a way that supports integer and slice indices without manually checking the type of the argument?

I see a lot of examples of this form, but it seems very hacky to me.

```
def __getitem__(self,key):
  if isinstance(key,int):
    # do integery foo here
  if isinstance(key,slice):
    # do slicey bar here
```

On a related note, why does this problem exist in the first place? Somtimes returning an int and sometimes a slice is weird design. Calling `foo[4]` should call `foo.__getitem__(slice(4,5,1))` or similar.

Comment: `key` doesn't have to an integer, so trying to force it into a slice would be a little strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use exception handling; assume `key` is a `slice` object and call the `indices()` method on it. If that fails it must've been an integer:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    try:
        return [self.somelist[i] * 5 for i in key.indices(self.length)]
    except AttributeError:
        # not a slice object (no `indices` attribute)
        return self.somelist[key] * 5
```

**Most** use-cases for custom containers don't need to support slicing, and historically, the `__getitem__` method only ever had to handle integers (for sequences, that is); the [`__getslice__()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__) was there to handle slicing instead. When `__getslice__` was deprecated, for backwards compatibility *and* for simpler APIs it was easier to have `__getitem__` handle both integers and `slice` objects.

And that is ignoring the fact that outside sequences, `key` doesn't have to be an integer. Custom classes are free to support any key type they like.

Comment: Aha, that's a nice Pythonic way of doing it. Instead of testing an object for type, test that it has a particular method, the essence of duck typing. (Although I think I would use getattr instead of catching an exception)

Obviously I have a use-case for slicing and indexing or I wouldn't be asking the question...